# Can't Add Authorization Convention for Area Razor Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

Using .net Core 3.1 I followed the instructions in the official docs ([Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=netcore-cli)) to scaffold Identity onto my empty Web project.

I'm using claims-based authorization. In my **Startup.cs** file I created the following policy:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy =>
        {
            policy.RequireClaim("CanListUsers", true.ToString());
            policy.RequireClaim("CanEditUsers", true.ToString());
        });
});
```

and immediately after that I am gating certain *Area* pages, as follows:

```
services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Register", "Admin");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
});
```

I want to shut down registration to "Admin" users only. And I want to allow only signed in users to manage accounts.

I can't gate the Registration page. I can still access it without a logged-in user. Why not?

On the other hand, strangely, if I remove the authorization convention `/Account/Manage`, the page will redirect anonymous users to Login. How is that happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out both questions.

#### I can't gate the Registration page. I can still access it without a logged-in user. Why not?

The page was decorated with `[AllowAnonymous]`.  Clearly decorators have higher priority than *Conventions* set at configuration time.

#### On the other hand, strangely, if I remove the authorization convention `/Account/Manage`, the page will redirect anonymous users to `Login`. How is that happening?

I noticed that all the pages that should be accessible by not-logged-in users are decorated with `[AllowAnonymous]`. I'm thinking that the scaffolding, being an Identity template, assumes the implementer will eventually add

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

My thinking here is that these Middlewares automatically clamp down all pages, essentially strapping an `[Authorize]` attribute on all pages so that a page that can allow not-logged-in users needs to opt-out with a `[AllowAnonymous]`.

---

These are not much more than educated guesses, so please feel free to correct me in the comments